# Deserialize xml attribute with the same name from different elements

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I'm starting to look at XML (de)serialization and I'm struggling to deserialize the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Reader>
  <NewRecord value ="HH"/>
  <FileTerminator value ="HHProgram"/>
  <OutputFont value ="Courier"/>
</Reader>
```

Into the following class

```
public class Reader
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string NewRecord;
    [XmlElement]
    public string FileTerminator;
    [XmlElement]
    public string OutputFont;

}
```

I'm having trouble referencing the correct value attribute of each element where the following XML works as expected.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LayoutReader>
  <NewRecord>HH</NewRecord>
  <FileTerminator>HHProgram</FileTerminator>
  <OutputFont>Courier</OutputFont>
</LayoutReader>
```

Comment: The latter works without tweaking because you have values for elements there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this code, it works as you expect. Also you can add other property the same way

```
public class Reader
{
    ...
    [XmlElement("OutputFont")]
    public ReaderItemOutputFont ReaderItem { get; set; }
}


[Serializable()]
public class ReaderItemOutputFont
{
    [XmlAttribute("value")]
    public String OutputFont { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me -

```
[XmlRoot]
public class Reader
{
    [XmlElement]
    public NewRecord NewRecord;

    [XmlElement]
    public FileTerminator FileTerminator;

    [XmlElement]
    public OutputFont OutputFont;
}

public class NewRecord
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string value;

}

public class FileTerminator
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string value;

}

public class OutputFont
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string value;
}


var t = o.Deserialize("xml"); // works
```